# Django set_password no attribute

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to use the set_password() function but this error

```
'Member' object has no attribute 'set_password'
```

comes up when I use it. If I take out the set_password() function the password is stored in the database but without being hashed.

**view.py**

```
user = Member(username=u, password=p, email=e, security=s)
user.set_password(p)
user.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Member(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16,primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=325)
    security = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, null=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)
    from_member_id = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: `set_password()` is a method of `models.User` not `models.Model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message tells you, the method `set_password` is not defined. 
Either you implement it yourself, or (better) create your `Member` model by subclassing django's `AbrstactBaseUser`:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16,primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=325)
    security = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, null=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)
    from_member_id = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

You can find more about custom user models in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 6):

The `set_password` function is not automatically provided by `models.Model`. 
You have to define it by yourself or derive `Member` from django Usermodel

Answer (score 3):

The documentation on [providing your own user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) is quite clear and comprehensive. Among other things, your model must be a subclass of AbstractBaseUser, which is what provides the `set_password` method.

Also note that 16 characters is not nearly long enough to store a hashed, salted password.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your doing this but it is probably easier to make the model with OneToOneField(User) and give it additional fields. You just need to remember to save in the new fields or the fields wont show up when u call.
Where you set the `user_form=Member(request.POST)`

```
user = user_form.save()
user.set_password(user.password)
profile = user.userprofile
profile.bio = request.POST['bio']
profile.save()
```